# System.NullReferenceException HResult=0x80004003 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an error when trying to run my MVC ASP.NET C# web application for the shared layout razor page.
The error I faced is at the code:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top height5">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="make-small-nav">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Applicant Tracking System"].ToLower().ToString() == "true")
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Applicant Tracking System" + @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""], "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.ActionLink(@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Applicant Tracking System"], "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            }

        </div>
        <div style="float:right">
            @if (Session["username"] != null)
            {
               <text> Welcome, @Session["username"].ToString()!</text><span>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "fa fa-sign-out fa-2x" })
                </span>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

I was expecting to make a menu button to hover down the side bar menu for the code:

```
        <div class="maincover LeftBar">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <div class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <div class="Ul-span">MASTER MAINTENANCE</div>
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <a class="list-group-item" role="button" href="@Url.Action("PositionList", "Position")"><span class="fa fa-file"></span> <b>MM POSITION</b></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <a class="list-group-item" role="button" href="@Url.Action("CandidateList", "Candidate")"><span class="fa fa-file"></span> <b>MM CANDIDATE</b></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Ul-span">INTERVIEW TRACKING</div>
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <a class="list-group-item" role="button" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Interview")"><span class="fa fa-file"></span> <b>INTERVIEW</b></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is there any ways to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible null return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[KeyName] If KeyName Not Exists In AppSettings

Please Check your web.config appsettings section.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).